# how to generate list of (unique) words from text file in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unique, words

I have an ASCII text file. I want to generate a list of all "words" from that file using one or more Ubuntu commands. A word is defined as an alpha-num sequence between delimiters. Delimiters are by default whitespaces but I also want to experiment with other characters like punctuation etc. IN other words, i want to be able to specify a delimiter char set. How do I produce only a unique set of words? What if I also want to list only those words that are at least N characters long?

Comment: Basically you need a bash or more generally a shell script.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use grep:

`-E '\w+'` searches for words

`-o` only prints the portion of the line that matches `% cat temp`

Some examples use "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog,"
rather than "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
for example text.

## if you don't care whether words repeat

```
% grep -o -E '\w+' temp
Some
examples
use
The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog
rather
than
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
for
example
text
```

If you want to only print each word once, disregarding case, you can use sort

`-u` only prints each word once

`-f` tells sort to ignore case when comparing words

## if you only want each word once

```
% grep -o -E '\w+' temp | sort -u -f
adipiscing
amet
brown
consectetur
dog
dolor
elit
example
examples
for
fox
ipsum
jumped
lazy
Lorem
over
quick
rather
sit
Some
text
than
The
use
```

you can also use the `tr` command

```
echo the quick brown fox jumped over the lazydog | tr -cs 'a-zA-Z0-9' '\n'
the
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazydog
```

The `-c` is for the complement of the specified characters; the `-s` squeezes out duplicates of the replacements; the 'a-zA-Z0-9' is the set of alphanumerics, if you add a character here, the input won't get delimited on that character (see another example below); the '\n' is the replacement character (newline).

```
echo the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy-dog | tr -cs 'a-zA-Z0-9-' '\n'
the
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy-dog
```

As we added '-' in the list of non-delimiters list, lazy-dog was printed. Other the output is

```
echo the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy-dog | tr -cs 'a-zA-Z0-9' '\n'
the
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog
```

Summary for tr: any character not in argument of `-c`, will act as a delimiter. I hope this solves your delimiter problem too.

Comment: If you wanted this to work against a directory( along with its subdirectories) then just do `grep -o -E -r '\w+' . | sort -u -f` the `-r` is so it recursively searches for subdirectories. the `.` _directory_ replaces the `temp` _file_

Comment: This is a great answer! Just wanted to add: If you want to catch contractions (can't, I've) you can use this pattern instead: `grep -o -E "\w+('\w+)*"`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my word-cloud like chain

`cat myfile | grep -o -E '\w+' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

if you have a tex file, replace `cat` with `detex`:

`detex myfile | grep -o -E '\w+' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work for you:

```
tr \ \\t\\v\\f\\r \\n | | tr -s \\n | tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9\\n | LC_ALL=C sort | uniq
```

If you want the characters that are at least five characters long, pipe the output of `tr` through `grep .....`.  If you want case-insensitivity, stick `tr A-Z a-z` someplace in the pipeline before `sort`.

Note that `LC_ALL=C` is necessary for `sort` to work correctly.

I'd recommend reading the `man` pages for ant commands you don't understand here.