# number of unique words in a document

Tags: bash, text, grep

I have a very large txt file (500GiB), and I want to get the number of its unique words. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16489317/3639557), but it seems  to be very slow as it does sort:

```
grep -o -E '\w+' temp | sort -u -f | wc -l
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have 500 GiB spare disk space?

Comment: Try `awk` (throw words into an awk associative array) and see if that's fast enough. If not, I would write a custom program in C++ (or something of that nature).

Comment: @rici yes (and here are a few more words to fulfil the reply's characters limit)

Comment: Sorry, the passing idea i had didn't turn out to be faster.

Comment: The bash uniq program does not seem to solve it, but why not?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS=" " '{a[$0]++} END{for(k in a) sum++; print sum}' file
```

UPDATE:

It's probably better to do preprocessing with `tr` and let the `awk` do the counting economically. You may want to delimit the words with spaces or new lines.

For example:

```
$ tr ':;,?!\"' ' ' < file | tr -s ' ' '\n' | awk '!a[$0]++{c++} END{print c}'
```

Comment: A promising approach, but by setting `RS` to `" "` (a single space), you're mistakenly including the line-ending `\n` in each line's last word, and you're also counting the empty words between _multiple_ adjacent spaces.

Comment: +1 for the elegant `awk` script, but, given the size of the file and performance concerns, it's probably better to make do with just _one_ `tr` call and to use a field loop in `awk` instead. Also note that the OP wanted case-insensitivity.

Comment: I don't think size matters much considering how pipe works. Also `tr` is lightning fast. If all unique words is more than the memory can hold it might be an issue though.

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on `awk`'s default behavior to split lines into words by runs of whitespace, and use its associative arrays:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[tolower($i)]++ } END { print length(a) }' file
```

<sup>**Update**: As @rici points out in a comment, white-space separated tokens may include punctuation other than `_` and other characters, and are thus not necessarily the same as `grep`'s `\w+` construct. @4ae1e1 therefore suggests using a field separator of along the lines of `'[^[:alnum:]_]'`. Note that this will result in each component of a hyphenated word to be counted separately; similarly, `'` separates words.</sup>

```
awk -F '[^[:alnum:]_]+' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { a[tolower($i)]++ } }
        END { print length(a) - ("" in a) }' file
```

- Associative array `a` is built in a way that counts the occurrence of each distinct word encountered in the input, converted to lowercase first so as to ignore differences in case - if you do NOT want to ignore case differences, simply remove the `tolower()` call.

  - CAVEAT: It seems that Mawk and BSD Awk aren't locale-aware, so `tolower()` won't work properly with non-ASCII characters.
- On having processed all words, the number of elements of `a` equals the number of unique words.

  - NOTE: The POSIX-compliant reformulation of `print length(a)` is: `for (k in a) ++count; print count`

The above will work with GNU Awk, Mawk (1.3.4+), and BSD Awk, even though it isn't *strictly* POSIX-compliant (POSIX defines the `length` function only for *strings*, not arrays).

Comment: That's nice, but an awk field is not normally the same as a grep word. `\w` is [_[:alnum]] iirc, so the I think the expectation is that "No! No? No, no." would contain one unique word, not four.

Comment: @rici Simple enough. Set `FS` to `[^[:alnum:]]+`, although things like `I'm` (in fact it's arguable if this is a word) and words with hyphen (could just add `-` to the char class, but still depends on whether there are `--` not wrapped by spaces masquerading as em-dash) would be problematic that way.

Comment: @4ae1e1: Thanks; I've added a solution based on `'[^[:alnum:]_]+'` (which also necessitated ignoring empty fields) and added a note.

Comment: @mklement0 I would say do not check for empty fields (which would result in branching for every single field and would certainly be a performance hit — at least theoretically), and just subtract one from the final result.

Comment: @4ae1e1: Good point; while you can't subtract _blindly_, a simple check in the `END` block for the presence of an empty-string key in `a` is preferable to checking each input field - updated.

Comment: @rici: What? No! No? No, no. Just kidding. Good point - I've updated the answer based on  4ae1e1's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

An important feature of sorting is that it is locale-aware, and therefore much more expensive in any locale other than C. Since you don't really care about the order here, you might as well tell sort to ignore the locale by using `LC_ALL=C sort -u -f`. If your locale is set to something else, that will probably cut your execution time in half.

The original version of this answer suggested that you should only do this if you don't care about non-ascii characters. However, if you are using Gnu coreutils, it turns out that none of this stuff will work in UTF-8 locales. While gnu `sort` will do a locale-aware string comparison in any locale (using the `strxfrm` standard library function), `sort -f` only does locale-aware case-folding in single-byte locales. Gnu `uniq -i` has the same problem. And `tr` only translates single-byte characters (by design, afaik); in theory `[:alpha:]` is locale-aware, but only for characters representable as single bytes.

In short, if you want to use `sort -u -f`, you might as well specify the `C` locale. That is no less broken for non-English letters, but at least the breakage doesn't waste time.

Gnu `awk`'s `tolower()` function does apparently work on multibyte locales. So check out one of the `awk` answers if you need this to work in a UTF-8 locale.